# Did bootstrap 5 remove spacing between row?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I started using bootstrap 5 and noticed there is no spaces between rows. Do we have to explicitly use [spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) utility like `mb-3` or `mb-2` etc Trying to understand the reason behind removing vertical spaces between rows.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3">
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
          Example checkbox
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5 has [vertical **gutters** for the Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#vertical-gutters). Instead of using separate rows, put the columns in a single `row` div. Then use whichever `gy-*` you want on the row...

```
  <form>
        <div class="row gy-4">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
            </div>
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1"> Example checkbox </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

https://codeply.com/p/4ZM75xw90B

Comment: What would be the correct use case if my row is not taking the full 12 boostrap columns? Should one use the `m-x` in those cases?