# How to set margin between two rows in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How to set space between two rows in bootstrap, if we using **row** class for every row, it is very easy to set margin or padding. But while set all the column under one **row** class, not able to set the margin. Kindly check the following code.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 2</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 3</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 4</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 5</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 6</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 7</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 8</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 9</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 10</div>
</div>
```

In the above code how can I set margin for every row?

I can set margin, if the code is in the below format but it won't give responsive grid. Also the col-md-* and col-sm-* class is waste, we can only use col-* class.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 1</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 2</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 5</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 6</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 7</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 8</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 9</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: row should have 12 columns ... add classes to rows and You can always add maring: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important for every row

Answer (score 2):

In each div class, add m-1 or m-2 as per your requirement to add margin from all sides. Use mt-1 or mt-2 to add only top margin and mb-1 or mb-2 for the bottom margin.
See this [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what vertical [Gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/#vertical-gutters) are for...

```
  <div class="row gy-5">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 7</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 8</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 9</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3"> Div 10</div>
  </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/g7ewLO9nbJ

Gutters `gy-*` are used to increase or [decrease vertical spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229590/did-bootstrap-5-remove-spacing-between-row/69234263#69234263) between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `row-gap: 10px;` syntax in your CSS file? It would go in the `.row` class. This should set a "margin" between every row in the div.

Comment: Is it will automatically add the space, if the row split?

Comment: @MerbinJoe Yes, if there are multiple rows, then each one will have a space between them.